# SSRS Column visibility based on drill down level

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I want to achieve a drill down report where based on the drill level a certain column should show, otherwise be hidden dynamically (without republishing).

These screens should help.

**1. Design View** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd2SU.jpg

**2. Preview - What I want (before Drill down)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bjqI.jpg

**3. Preview - What I want (after Drill Down)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMcoa.jpg

**4. Preview - What I want (after Drill up)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NowpF.jpg

The screens are just a dummy I made up.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
1. Drag a table on the report body, fill in 2 columns.
2. Select the column “col2”.
3. Set the property “hidden” to be “True”, and the property “Toggle item” to be a textbox.

Now, the report only shows “col1” and “col4” at the first time. After clicking the collapsed button, the column “col2” and the column “col3” will be shown.

Cheers!

Comment: I understand that you can link it to a textbox, but I need to link it to the group. I get an out of scope error when I try to set the Toggle Item as the Group textbox. Any ideas?
Plus if I have 3 columns, this method leaves empty space between col1 and col3, if I'm hiding col2.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure when linking to a group.